# Git, get unchaged files between commits

Tags: git, version-control

I've searched around a little but I can't find what I'm looking for. Hopefully someone on here can help.

Basically, I'd like to know if there is a way using git, to check for any files that haven't changed since a specific commit.

The reason for this, is that I'm working on a project checked into git, that had a bunch of files added unnecessarily in the initial commit, which is now making it difficult to differentiate between what are actually (used) files, and what was added by accident.

I'm hoping that I can use git to get all these files, and just remove.

Thanks in regards.

Comment: You may need to be more specific. Suppose, e.g., someone makes a commit adding `f1` and `f2`. Five commits later, someone else modifies `f2` (but not `f1`), then makes another commit changing `f2` back, then all commits after that touch neither file. Are both files unchanged, or do we discount `f2` because it did change once?

Comment: Hi @torek - sorry for the lack of specificity. The solution posted below by Vampire works for what I needed. For clarity - in your example, both files (f1 and f2) should be considered "unchanged".

Comment: OK; note that Vampire's solution would *not* consider `f2` unchanged. Your problem is simpler: just run `git diff --name-status` on the two commits and then, starting from the list of names in the first commit, throw out all files shown as modified (or, perhaps, renamed, hence the desire for "status" in `--name-status`; if renames are not an issue use `--no-renames` and `--name-only`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only <commit-ish 1> | grep -vFxf <(git log <commit-ish 1>..<commit-ish 2> -c --name-only --no-renames --pretty=format: | sort -u)
```

`git log <commit-ish 1>..<commit-ish 2> -c --name-only --no-renames --pretty=format: | sort -u` lists all files that were touched between `1` and `2`, even if a file was changed and then changed back to its original state.

`git ls-tree -r --name-only <commit-ish 1>` lists all files of `1`.

`grep -vFxf` excludes all finds of the first command from the finds of the second command, resulting in the files that were never touched.